# Keyboard moving over the content when typing

Tags: android, listview, keyboard

I'm using a listview which displays several EditTexts. When I click on an EditText, the content is correctly panned so that it's not hidden by the keyboard (I used  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in the Manifest in order to do that). However, the problem is that when I start typing on the keyboard, all the content goes back to its initial position and so it is hidden by the keyboard.

This only occures on the device I'm testing on, the Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 running Android 4.1.2 and there is no problem on the emulator.

Any ideas?

Thanks by advance, Valentin

Answer (score 0):

just put ScrollView as Parent in your `list_item_layout.xml`. Like:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/app_name" >
</EditText></ScrollView>
```

Comment: The EditText is already in a LinearLayout which is then included in a ListView. I don't understand why using a scrollview as parent would help. Anyway, I tried and it didn't changed anything.